# Why arent these functions within the main functional component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I don't understand why these formatter functions are placed outside the main component called TemplateTable.

If you need to use the actionformatter for example, you cannot pass a dispatch function do it correct?

I had an issue trying to set the actionformatter onClick for the delete button to a dispatch(deleteTemplate()).

When I run the code while the actionformatter is outside the main component TemplateTable, I get dispatch is undefined. When I defined dispatch within the component I obviously get the cannot use react hooks ouside function component problem.

I can fix this whole issue by just including the actionformatter inside the block of templateTable. I just feel like im shortcutting and was wondering if anyone had any input on this

```
import React, { createRef, Fragment, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Col,
  CustomInput,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  InputGroup,
  Media,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  Row,
  UncontrolledDropdown
} from 'reactstrap';
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import FalconCardHeader from '../common/FalconCardHeader';
import ButtonIcon from '../common/ButtonIcon';
import paginationFactory, { PaginationProvider } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Flex from '../common/Flex';
import Avatar from '../common/Avatar';
import { getPaginationArray } from '../../helpers/utils';
import CreateTemplate from '../templates/CreateTemplate';
import customers from '../../data/e-commerce/customers';
import { listTemplates, deleteTemplate } from '../../actions/index';


const nameFormatter = (dataField, { template }) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/pages/customer-details">
      <Media tag={Flex} align="center">
        <Media body className="ml-2">
          <h5 className="mb-0 fs--1">{template}</h5>
        </Media>
      </Media>
    </Link>
  );
};

const bodyFormatter = (dataField, { avatar, body }) => {
  return (
    <Link to="/pages/customer-details">
      <Media tag={Flex} align="center">
        
        <Media body className="ml-2">
          <h5 className="mb-0 fs--1">{body}</h5>
        </Media>
      </Media>
    </Link>
  );
};

const emailFormatter = email => <a href={`mailto:${email}`}>{email}</a>;
const phoneFormatter = phone => <a href={`tel:${phone}`}>{phone}</a>;

const actionFormatter = (dataField, { _id }) => ( 
  // Control your row with this id
  
  <UncontrolledDropdown>
    <DropdownToggle color="link" size="sm" className="text-600 btn-reveal mr-3">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ellipsis-h" className="fs--1" />
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu right className="border py-2">
      <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('Edit: ', _id)}>Edit</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem onClick={} className="text-danger">
        Delete
      </DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </UncontrolledDropdown>
  );

const columns = [
  {
    dataField: 'name',

    text: 'Name',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: nameFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'content',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Content',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: bodyFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'joined',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Last modified',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    sort: true,
    align: 'right',
    headerAlign: 'right'
  },
  {
    dataField: '',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Actions',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: actionFormatter,
    align: 'right'
  }
];

const SelectRowInput = ({ indeterminate, rowIndex, ...rest }) => (
  <div className="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input
      className="custom-control-input"
      {...rest}
      onChange={() => {}}
      ref={input => {
        if (input) input.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }}
    />
    <label className="custom-control-label" />
  </div>
);

const selectRow = onSelect => ({
  mode: 'checkbox',
  columnClasses: 'py-2 align-middle',
  clickToSelect: false,
  selectionHeaderRenderer: ({ mode, ...rest }) => <SelectRowInput type="checkbox" {...rest} />,
  selectionRenderer: ({ mode, ...rest }) => <SelectRowInput type={mode} {...rest} />,
  headerColumnStyle: { border: 0, verticalAlign: 'middle' },
  selectColumnStyle: { border: 0, verticalAlign: 'middle' },
  onSelect: onSelect,
  onSelectAll: onSelect
});



const TemplateTable = ( props ) => {
  
  let table = createRef();
  // State
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);
  const [showTemplateModal, setShowTemplateModal] = useState(false);
  const handleNextPage = ({ page, onPageChange }) => () => {
    onPageChange(page + 1);
  };


  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const deleteHandler = (_id) => {
    dispatch(deleteHandler())
  }
  
 useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(listTemplates())
}, [])
  
  const handlePrevPage = ({ page, onPageChange }) => () => {
    onPageChange(page - 1);
  };

  const onSelect = () => {
    setImmediate(() => {
      setIsSelected(!!table.current.selectionContext.selected.length);
    });
  };

  const options = {
  
    custom: true,
    sizePerPage: 12,
    totalSize: props.templates.length
    
  };
  
  return (
    <Card className="mb-3">
      <FalconCardHeader light={false}>
      
        {isSelected ? (
          <InputGroup size="sm" className="input-group input-group-sm">
            <CustomInput type="select" id="bulk-select">
              <option>Bulk actions</option>
              <option value="Delete">Delete</option>
              <option value="Archive">Archive</option>
            </CustomInput>
            <Button color="falcon-default" size="sm" className="ml-2">
              Apply
            </Button>
          </InputGroup>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <ButtonIcon onClick={(() => setShowTemplateModal(true))}icon="plus" transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm">
              New Template
            </ButtonIcon>
            <Modal isOpen={showTemplateModal} centered toggle={() => setShowTemplateModal(!showTemplateModal)}>
          <ModalBody className="p-0">
            <Card>
              <CardBody className="fs--1 font-weight-normal p-4"> 
                <CreateTemplate />
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </ModalBody>
        </Modal>
            <ButtonIcon icon="fa-download" transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm" className="mx-2">
              Download
            </ButtonIcon>
            <ButtonIcon icon="external-link-alt" transform="shrink-3 down-2" color="falcon-default" size="sm">
              Expand View
            </ButtonIcon>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </FalconCardHeader>
      <CardBody className="p-0">
        <PaginationProvider pagination={paginationFactory(options)}>
          {({ paginationProps, paginationTableProps }) => {
            const lastIndex = paginationProps.page * paginationProps.sizePerPage;
            
            return (
              <Fragment>
                
                <div className="table-responsive">
                  <BootstrapTable
                    ref={table}
                    bootstrap4
                    keyField="_id"
                    data={props.templates}
                    columns={columns}
                    selectRow={selectRow(onSelect)}
                    bordered={false}
                    classes="table-dashboard table-striped table-sm fs--1 border-bottom border-200 mb-0 table-dashboard-th-nowrap"
                    rowClasses="btn-reveal-trigger border-top border-200"
                    headerClasses="bg-200 text-900 border-y border-200"
                    {...paginationTableProps}
                  />
                </div>
                <Row noGutters className="px-1 py-3 flex-center">
                  <Col xs="auto">
                    <Button
                      color="falcon-default"
                      size="sm"
                      onClick={handlePrevPage(paginationProps)}
                      disabled={paginationProps.page === 1}
                    >
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-left" />
                    </Button>
                    {getPaginationArray(paginationProps.totalSize, paginationProps.sizePerPage).map(pageNo => (
                      <Button
                        color={paginationProps.page === pageNo ? 'falcon-primary' : 'falcon-default'}
                        size="sm"
                        className="ml-2"
                        onClick={() => paginationProps.onPageChange(pageNo)}
                        key={pageNo}
                      >
                        {pageNo}
                      </Button>
                    ))}
                    <Button
                      color="falcon-default"
                      size="sm"
                      className="ml-2"
                      onClick={handleNextPage(paginationProps)}
                      disabled={lastIndex >= paginationProps.totalSize}
                    >
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="chevron-right" />
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Fragment>
            );}
          }
        </PaginationProvider>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    templates: state.templates,
    auth: state.auth,
    deleteTemplate: state.deleteTemplate
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { listTemplates })(TemplateTable);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that as-is there isn't any dependency on anything from a consuming component, so it makes complete sense to externalize these declarations from the `TemplateTable` component.

While you could *just* move code back into the component to close over any dependencies in the enclosure of the functional component body I think we can do better.

I suggest currying the `dispatch` function to any of the specific formatters that need it, i.e.

```
const actionFormatter = ({ dispatch }) => (dataField, { _id }) => ( 
  // Control your row with this id
  
  <UncontrolledDropdown>
    <DropdownToggle color="link" size="sm" className="text-600 btn-reveal mr-3">
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon="ellipsis-h" className="fs--1" />
    </DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu right className="border py-2">
      <DropdownItem onClick={() => console.log('Edit: ', _id)}>Edit</DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem
        onClick={() => dispatch(deleteTemplate())}
        className="text-danger"
      >
        Delete
      </DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </UncontrolledDropdown>
);
```

And turn `columns` into a factory function in order to receive and pass on configurations, i.e.

```
const columns = ({ dispatch }) => ([ // <-- consume config & destructure
  {
    dataField: 'name',

    text: 'Name',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: nameFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'content',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Content',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: bodyFormatter,
    sort: true
  },
  {
    dataField: 'joined',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Last modified',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    sort: true,
    align: 'right',
    headerAlign: 'right'
  },
  {
    dataField: '',
    headerClasses: 'border-0',
    text: 'Actions',
    classes: 'border-0 py-2 align-middle',
    formatter: actionFormatter({ dispatch }), // <-- pass dispatch
    align: 'right'
  }
]);
```

Create the columns configuration object and pass to the table.

```
const config = { dispatch };

...

<BootstrapTable
  ref={table}
  bootstrap4
  keyField="_id"
  data={props.templates}
  columns={columns(config)} // <-- pass config to factory
  selectRow={selectRow(onSelect)}
  bordered={false}
  classes="table-dashboard table-striped table-sm fs--1 border-bottom border-200 mb-0 table-dashboard-th-nowrap"
  rowClasses="btn-reveal-trigger border-top border-200"
  headerClasses="bg-200 text-900 border-y border-200"
  {...paginationTableProps}
/>
```

Comment: Drew, Thank you for this thorough explanation. How do you get your mind to think like this? I need to learn destructuring better... Any good course material you recommend or personal projects you like to build or find challenging?

Comment: @AmandaConda Honestly, it's probably mostly from seeing/reading/reviewing code written by developers more experienced than me, which forces me to spend time breaking it down so I understand how it resolves *a* problem, i.e. understanding both the problem and solution. After a while you develop a design pattern repertoire *and* learn to recognize problems more generally, and then it's just matching problems to known general solutions and tailoring to fit. Has my answer sufficiently answered/resolved your question/issue, or do you have further question or concern?

Comment: Hey Drew, Yep you helped me out alot. I have been thinking a little different about how to approach problems.